# Prove by induction ${\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n}(1+x^{2k-1}})$= $\frac{1-x^{2n}}{1-x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove by induction ${\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n}(1+x^{2k-1}}) = \frac{1-x^{2n}}{1-x} .$

We start verifying for $n = 1$:

${\prod\limits_{k=1}^{1}(1+x^{2k-1}})=  $$\frac{1-x^{2(1)}}{1-x}$

${\prod\limits_{k=1}^{1}(1+x^{2k-1}})=  $ $\frac{1-x^{2}}{1-x}$

${\prod\limits_{k=1}^{1}(1+x})=  $ $\frac{{(1+x)(1-x)}}{1-x}$

${\prod\limits_{k=1}^{1}(1+x})= $ $(1+x)$

Then we accept that the equation is valid for n and we have to n + 1.

${\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n+1}(1+x^{2k-1}})=  $$\frac{1-x^{2(n+1)}}{1-x}$

${\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n+1}(1+x^{2k-1}})=  $$\frac{1-x^{(2n+2)}}{1-x}$

Now the problem is that I have come to develop up to the part where the multiplication of

$(\frac{1-x^{2n}}{1-x})(1+x^{2(n+1)-1})$

I did the math but it does not give me the expected result. Maybe I put the operation wrong.

From that point I have no idea how to continue.

Comment: Hint: $1-x^{2}=(1+x)(1-x)$.

Comment: Another hint:  Write $\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n+1} (1 + x^{2k - 1}) = \prod\limits_{k=1}^n (1+x^{2k -1}) \cdot (1 + x^{2(n+1) -1})$.  Then simplify.

Comment: It looks like Donald proved the correct version of the statement below. It should be $x^{2^{k-1}}$ and $x^{2^n}$. Otherwise, as you say, the statement is false.

Answer (score 2):

Proof by induction: clearly true when $n=1$.

The inductive hypothesis is
\begin{eqnarray*}
\prod_{k=1}^{n}(1+x^{2^{k-1}}) =\frac{1-x^{2^n}}{1-x}.
\end{eqnarray*}
The inductive step is
\begin{eqnarray*}
\prod_{k=1}^{n+1}(1+x^{2^{k-1}}) =(1+x^{2^{n}}) \prod_{k=1}^{n}(1+x^{2^{k-1}})= (1+x^{2^{n}})\frac{1-x^{2^n}}{1-x}=\frac{1-x^{2^{n+1}}}{1-x}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Big difference between the equation as stated ($x^{2k-1}$) and as used in this proof ($x^{2^{k-1}}$).